# Contitional Statement to delete temperature above a certain degree

Tags: r

I am trying to write a conditional statement in order to delete all the temperature values above 27 degrees.

I wrote this line of code, but it is not working:

```r
for (i in 1:length(New_DF$Temperature)) {
  if(New_DF$Temperature[i] > 27) {
    New_DF$Temperature <- NA
  }
}
```

And I would like to delete the whole row that has a temperature above 27 degrees.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will find you get better answers if you do some research first, both on SO norms and on R itself.  This is basic R, covered in the first chapter or two of any introductory text.

For instance, your question should be reproducible: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

With that said, rather than trying to write a loop to do this, use a vector to select the items you need, and delete them from the data.frame:

```
selector <- New_DF$Temperature>27
New_DF <- New_DF[ !selector, ]
```

Or in one line:

```
New_DF[ !New_DF$Temperature>27, ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but this actually deletes all the temperature values below 27 and keep the temperature values above 27 in the data frame. How can I do the opposite?

Comment: Again, just read a basic introduction.  If you take away the NOT operator (the !), it will invert.  Or flip the > to a <.

Comment: Exactly, but why isn't it diving me the data with temperature less than 27?

Answer (score 2):

Easier just to filter your data set. No need for a loop.

```
library(dplyr)

filtered_DF <- filter(New_DF, Temperature < 27)
```

you can also use base R's subset

```
filtered_DF <- subset(New_DF, Temperature < 27)
```

Comment: when I run your line of code I get '<' not meaningful for factors even though Temperature is numeric. Do you know why I get this? Many thanks!

Comment: str(New_DF) and see what classes everything is. let me know what it comes out as

Comment: I checked, it tells me that all my variables are factors, however when I use mode(New_DF$Temperature) I get that Temperature is numeric

Comment: use class(New_DF$Temperature) to find out what class it is. str(New_DF) is your best friend to see what classes all of your variables are. for whatever reason, your df is all factors. I'm not sure how it was imported. 
try New_DF$Temperature <- as.numeric(New_DF$Temperature). If there are NA's in your set, it will be as.numeric(New_DF$Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)
That will convert Temperature into a numeric class, and then run the answer above and it should work

Comment: when I change from factor to numeric all the values change. for example 122 becomes 132. this will change the whole condition.

Comment: can you post a few lines of your df so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the table here. But imagine you have 3 columns, x,y and z and you want to delete the rows which have y value > 27. The problem now is that when I convert from factor to numeric the values change, for example, 27 will become 84.

Comment: @MattW. you don't convert factors to numeric like that - as.numeric returns the *level* integer. Use `as.numeric(as.character(somefactor))` !

Comment: @Spacedman that is true! I used as.numeric(as.character()) and it worked.

Comment: @Spacedman ahh you're right, thanks for that edit.